# Beautifulsoup url loading error

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

So I am trying to get the content of [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colornames.asp) using beautiful soup. I want to create a dictionary of all the css color names and this seemed like a quick and easy way to access this. So naturally I did the quick basic:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = 'http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colornames.asp'
soup = bs(url)
```

for some reason I am only getting the url in a `p` tag inside the body and that's it:

```
>>> print soup.prettify()
<html>
 <body>
  <p>
   http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colornames.asp
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

**why wont BeautifulSoup give me access to the information I need?**

Comment: no, beautifulsoup is working just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beautifulsoup does **not** load a URL for you.

You need to pass in the full HTML page, which means you need to load it from the URL first. Here is a sample using the [`urllib2.urlopen` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) to achieve that:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

source = urlopen(url).read()
soup = bs(source)
```

Now you can extract the colours just fine:

```
css_table = soup.find('table', class_='reference')
for row in css_table.find_all('tr'):
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    if cells:
        print cells[0].a.text, cells[1].a.text
```

Comment: wow, I knew that! that's a serious brain fart on my part. Thanks!

Comment: so this answers my question...but beautiful soup is now parsing incorrectly...it get everything except the section I need. the section I need appears as such: ` t d   a l i g n = " l e f t " &gt; a   h r e f = " / t a g s / r e f _ c o l o r m i x e r . a s p ? c o l o r b o t t o m = E E E 8 A A &amp;c o l o r t o p = F F F F F F " &gt; M i x / a &gt; / t d &gt; `...why is this

Comment: Sounds like you are looping over text instead; python strings are sequences of characters, loop over a string and you get to handle each individual character from that text.

Comment: yes, that seems like what it is...but I didn't go through a loop. that is what I get when I print `soup`, so your `.find` wont find any tables due to the fact that beautiful soup seems to have parsed incorrectly...is that a bug?

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing; I tested the code in my answer; I suggest you run the same code first to see what happens. :-)

Comment: when I run your code I get: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'`

Comment: And what does `source` contain? Not a HTML page with a table with `class="reference"` at the very least.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35016/discussion-between-ryan-saxe-and-martijn-pieters)